# setVisible(true) on java Swing doesn't work

Tags: java

I'm working on a project "building a podcast plate form" with Java *Swing*.
I've created a multiple "Application window" in the same package but in order to open a frame when I click on a button it doesn't work. I've used `setVisible(true)`.
Here is a part of my code:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

public class Acceuil_After {

private JFrame Acceuil_After;
private JTextField textField2;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Acceuil_After window = new Acceuil_After();
                window.Acceuil_After.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public Acceuil_After() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
.........
//----JButton -----------------------------------------------------------------------------         
    JButton B_Acceuil_After1 = new JButton("Acceuil");
    B_Acceuil_After1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            Acceuil_After after = new Acceuil_After();
            after.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    B_Acceuil_After1.setBackground(new Color(77, 77, 77));
    B_Acceuil_After1.setForeground(new Color(250, 234, 115));
    B_Acceuil_After1.setFont(new Font("Century", Font.PLAIN, 17));
    B_Acceuil_After1.setBorderPainted(false);
    
    JButton podcast1 = new JButton("Nos podcasts");
    podcast1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            Acceuil_After after = new Acceuil_After();
            after.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    podcast1.setBackground(new Color(77, 77, 77));
    podcast1.setFont(new Font("Century", Font.PLAIN, 17));
    podcast1.setForeground(new Color(250, 234, 115));
    podcast1.setBorderPainted(false);
    
    JButton guide1 = new JButton("Guide d'écoute");
    guide1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            Acceuil_After after = new Acceuil_After();
            after.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    guide1.setBackground(new Color(77, 77, 77));
    guide1.setFont(new Font("Century", Font.PLAIN, 17));
    guide1.setForeground(new Color(250, 234, 115));
    guide1.setBorderPainted(false);
    
    JButton B_inscrit11 = new JButton("S'inscrire");
    B_inscrit11.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            Acceuil_After after = new Acceuil_After();
            after.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    B_inscrit11.setForeground(new Color(77, 77, 77));
    B_inscrit11.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 17));
    B_inscrit11.setBackground(new Color(250, 234, 115));
    B_inscrit11.setBorderPainted(false);
   /* .............
    ............. */
        public void setVisible(boolean b) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
}
```

I had tried with `addActionListener` instead of `addMouseListener` but no difference.

Hello, thank you for your answers !!
I've modified my code "I've used -class'- instead of -Application Window".
-> The problem that arises now is that nothing is displayed except an empty window without any of the compounds I put in".
Here is my new code

```
    public class Acceuil implements ActionListener{
    JFrame acceuil = new JFrame();
    
    JButton inscrire = new JButton("S'inscrire");
    JButton connecter = new JButton("Se connecter");
    JButton subscribe = new JButton("S'inscrire");
    JButton B_acc = new JButton("Acceuil");
    JButton B_pod = new JButton("Nos podcasts");
    JButton B_gui = new JButton("Guide d'écoute");
    
    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("COGITO");
    
    JTextArea textt = new JTextArea();
    JTextField textFieldd = new JTextField();


Acceuil()
{
//---JFrame ------------------------------------------------------
    acceuil.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(77, 77, 77));
    acceuil.setTitle("Acceuil");
    acceuil.setVisible(true);
    acceuil.setLayout(null);
    acceuil.setBounds(100, 100, 1297, 842);
    acceuil.setSize(2000, 5000);
    acceuil.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    
    acceuil.add(B_acc);
    acceuil.add(B_gui);
    acceuil.add(B_pod);
    acceuil.add(acceuil);
    acceuil.add(connecter);
    acceuil.add(inscrire);
    acceuil.add(lblNewLabel);
    acceuil.add(subscribe);
    acceuil.add(textFieldd);
    acceuil.add(textt);

//----JButton ----------------------------------------------------
    inscrire.setBackground(new Color(250, 234, 115));
    inscrire.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    inscrire.setFont(new Font("Century", Font.PLAIN, 21));
    inscrire.addActionListener(this);
    
    
    connecter.setFont(new Font("Century", Font.PLAIN, 21));
    connecter.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
    connecter.setBackground(new Color(250, 234, 115));
    connecter.addActionListener(this);
    
    subscribe.setForeground(new Color(77, 77, 77));
    subscribe.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 17));
    subscribe.setBackground(new Color(250, 234, 115));
    subscribe.setBorderPainted(false);
    subscribe.addActionListener(this);
    
    B_acc.setFont(new Font("Century", Font.PLAIN, 17));
    B_acc.setForeground(new Color(250, 234, 115));
    B_acc.setBackground(new Color(77, 77, 77));
    B_acc.setBorderPainted(false);
    B_acc.addActionListener(this);
    
    B_pod.setFont(new Font("Century", Font.PLAIN, 17));
    B_pod.setForeground(new Color(250, 234, 115));
    B_pod.setBackground(new Color(77, 77, 77));
    B_pod.setBorderPainted(false);
    B_pod.addActionListener(this);
    
    B_gui.setForeground(new Color(250, 234, 115));
    B_gui.setBackground(new Color(77, 77, 77));
    B_gui.setFont(new Font("Century", Font.PLAIN, 17));
    B_gui.setBorderPainted(false);
    B_gui.addActionListener(this);
//----JLabel ------------------------------------------------------
    lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Century", Font.BOLD, 70));
    lblNewLabel.setForeground(new Color(250, 234, 115));
    lblNewLabel.setBackground(new Color(77, 77, 77));
    

    
//----JTextArea -------------------------------------------------
    textt.setFont(new Font("Century", Font.PLAIN, 21));
    textt.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    textt.setBackground(new Color(77, 77, 77));
    textt.setText("Votre aventure philosophique et littéraire");
    textt.setTabSize(20);
    
//----JTextField ------------------------------------------------
    textFieldd.setText("Titres des podcasts de la semaine");
    textFieldd.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    textFieldd.setBackground(new Color(77, 77, 77));
    textFieldd.setFont(new Font("Century", Font.PLAIN, 21));
    textFieldd.setColumns(10);
    textFieldd.setBorder(null);
    
}


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == inscrire)
    {
        acceuil.dispose();
        Inscription inscriptionn = new Inscription();
    }
    if(e.getSource() == connecter)
    {
        acceuil.dispose();
        Connexion guide = new Connexion();
    }
    if(e.getSource() == subscribe)
    {
        acceuil.dispose();
        Inscription inscription = new Inscription();
    }
    if(e.getSource() == B_pod)
    {
        acceuil.dispose();
        Inscription podcasts = new Inscription();
    }
    if(e.getSource() == B_gui)
    {
        acceuil.dispose();
        Guide guide = new Guide();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please never post images of text. They are not searchable, we cannot copy-paste... Always copy-paste the text and format it properly.

Comment: plus what @g00se said butt i did not notice you add anything to the frame you need to add ell those button and stuff to it

Comment: Remove `public void setVisible(boolean b) { }`

Comment: 1) *I have try "addActionListener"* - which is what you should be using for the JButton. Don't use the MouseListener 2) You override the setVisible(...) method of the frame but have no code. Get rid of the override.

Comment: [Avoid null layouts in Swing](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/114-avoid-null-layouts-in-swing)
Also, `setVisible()` should really be called by the class that creates and uses that class. If you must call `setVisible()` in the class's ctor like that, make it the *last* line

Answer (score 0):

I would like to thank everyone who answered and helped me.
Finally, I solved the problems I had.
Here's a part of my new code:

```
public class Acceuil  implements ActionListener{
    JFrame acceuil = new JFrame();
    
    GroupLayout groupLayout = new GroupLayout(acceuil.getContentPane());
   /* **************************************************************** */

   Acceuil()
   {
    //---JFrame ----------------------------------------------------------
    acceuil.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(77, 77, 77));
    acceuil.setTitle("Acceuil");
    acceuil.setVisible(true);
    acceuil.getContentPane().setLayout(groupLayout);
    acceuil.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);     
    
    acceuil.add(inscrire);
    acceuil.add(lblNewLabel);
    //.........................................
    
    //----Grouplayout ----------------------------------------------------
    
    groupLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(72)
                    .addComponent(inscrire, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 
        158, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 742, 
      Short.MAX_VALUE)
     //**********************************************************
        );
    
      groupLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(71)
                    
       .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(inscrire)
                        .addComponent(connecter))
                    .addGap(32)
                    .addComponent(lblNewLabel)
                    .addGap(16)
      //***************************************************
        );
    @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == inscrire)
    {
        acceuil.dispose();
        Inscription inscriptionn = new Inscription();
    }
   }}
```

Comment: You should move `setVisible` to the end - even if it's currently working

Comment: I'll do it, thank you for the advice.